# How do I add separate errorbars in ggplot to each item on the X axis?

Tags: r

I have this graph:

[image: Male and Female Heights]

Which shows male and female heights along with the confidence interval of 95% for the mean. There's an issue tho, I can't seem to show one confidence interval for Males and one for Females. Both of the errorbars appear on both labels in the x axis. Would you be able to help me adjust me code to show the female CI (in blue) on the Female range, and the male CI (in red) for the Male range?

Here's my plot code:

```
gSE <- ggplot(data = sample.Height, aes(x=sample, y=heightIn)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=heightFemale.sampleMean-0.7970899, ymax=heightFemale.sampleMean+0.7970899), colour="blue", width=.1) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=heightMale.sampleMean-1.0322975, ymax=heightMale.sampleMean+1.0322975), colour="red", width=.1) +
  labs(title = "Male and Female Heights", x = "Gender", y = "Heights in Inches") +
  theme_light()
gSE

Thank you,
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would first make a simple table of your mean and SE to use with `geom_errorbar`. Then you only need to have `geom_errorbar` included once in your `ggplot`.

Here's an example with made up data:

```
library(tidyverse)

sample.Stats <- sample.Height %>%
  group_by(sample) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean, se = sd(.)/sqrt(n())))

gSE <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = sample.Height, aes(x=sample, y=heightIn)) + 
  geom_errorbar(data=sample.Stats, aes(x=sample, ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se, color=sample), width=.1) +
  labs(title = "Male and Female Heights", x = "Gender", y = "Heights in Inches") +
  theme_light()

gSE
```

**Plot**

[image: plot with error bars]

**Data**

```
sample.Height <- data.frame(
  sample = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male"),
  heightIn = c(61, 60, 59, 66, 72, 70)
)
```